# "could not load glyph" in multiprocessing

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiprocessing, pathos

I'm running into an issue using pathos multiprocessing that runs figure saving function.

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
datasets = Pool().map(model_handler, analysisParams)
```

which throws

```
  File ".../lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2029, in draw_text
    font.set_text(s, 0.0, flags=LOAD_NO_HINTING)
RuntimeError: In set_text: could not load glyph
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wrapper.py", line 410, in <module>
    datasets = Pool().map(model_handler, analysisParams)
  File ".../lib/python3.6/site-packages/pathos/multiprocessing.py", line 137, in map
    return _pool.map(star(f), zip(*args)) # chunksize
  File ".../lib/python3.6/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 260, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File ".../lib/python3.6/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
RuntimeError: In set_text: could not load glyph
"""
```

My current understanding is that this occurs because glyph is being called simultaneously by multiple processes. The exception only happens when the number of parallel executions gets >3, which is consistent with that idea. I see that [one person's work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44666207/matplotlib-error-when-running-plotting-in-multiprocess) was simply to call savefig repeatedly until the command went through, but the parallelized function contains a ton of plots and I'd rather not need to wrap each one in a try statement. Does anyone have an idea about how avoid this exception when plotting figures in parallel? Thanks!!

**EDIT**
Minimal example per comment request.

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool

def model_handler(analysisParam):
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('agg')
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    figout = plt.figure(figsize=(1, 1))
    axes = figout.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    axes.scatter(range(1000), range(1000))
    figout.savefig('dummyfig{}.pdf'.format(analysisParam), format='pdf')
    return analysisParam

datasets_serial = []
for j in range(20):
    datasets_serial.append(model_handler(j))

datasets = Pool(20).map(model_handler, range(20))
```

Interestingly, if I replace the dataset_serial loop with `dataset_serial = map(model_handler, range(20))`, the pathos parallel pool executes with no problem, but if I convert the serial map object to a list (`print(list(dataset_serial))`), the glyph exception in the parallel pool comes back.

Comment: A [mcve] would surely help to find the cause of this. Only then, as a second step, one could try to find a better workaround.

Comment: updated with example @ImportanceOfBeingErnest